# В чем причина ошибки android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня в процессе работы появляется ошибка в android studio:

```
Stub index points to a file without PSI: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.UnknownFileType@6d80b53e
```

Эта ошибка появляется внизу в самом углу, в виде красного восклицательного знака. Я как-бы постоянно нажимаю clear, но все-равно не очень понятна причина возникновения этой ошибки. Если у кого-то уже появлялась подобная ошибка то буду рад если скажете как с ней бороться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так: `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`